# What's the official maven distribution of org.w3c.dom package?

Tags: java, maven, dom, repository, artifact

I need the sources of `org.w3c.dom.Document` to be available for the gwt compiler. The library itself is out of the box included in the JRE. I would prefer not to copy the sources directly into my project but to include an "official distribution" of those sources from the central maven repository. Is there a org.w3c.dom official sources distribution?

Something like

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.w3c.dom</groupId>
  <artifactId>dom</artifactId>
  <classifier>sources</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `org.w3c.dom` comes from the

> API Java™ Platform, Standard Edition.

[Documentation of the dom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/package-summary.html), you'll see that is already in the Java API this package, so the official is the documentation of the API of Java SE.

> **Package org.w3c.dom Description** Provides the interfaces for the
>   Document Object Model (DOM) which is a component API of the Java API
>   for XML Processing.

Comment: Ok, that's a fact. I'm not interested in using org.w3c.dom as a library, but to allow the gwtcompiler to access its sources. So I need a source distribution of this. The official out of the box org.w3c.dom distribution will not help me.

Answer (score 0):

when your are looking for external libraries for maven you can search them on https://search.maven.org/ . There are all common libraries listed and it shows you the needed information to import the library into your project.